# cpp vector type determined by other variable

Tags: c++

Say I have two method to process values, CumSum and CumProd; I have a string to determine which method will be used, choice. They are all inside a class, and choice is a class argument. CumSum and CumProd is a class to do the cumulative computation for every vector.

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

struct CumSum {
public:
    int result = 0;


    void Push(int& x)  {
        result += x;
    }

    int ReturnVal()
    {
        return result;
    }
};

struct CumProd {
public:
    int result = 1;


    void Push(int& x)  {
        result *= x;
    }

    int ReturnVal()
    {
        return result;
    }
};


class Example
{
public:
    const int vector_size = 10;
    std::string choice;
    std::vector<CumSum * if choice == "A" else CumProd *> methods;

public:
    Example(std::string method)
    {
        choice = method;
        for (size_t ii = 0; ii < vector_size; ++ii)
        {
            methods.push_back(choice == "A" ? new CumSum() : new CumProd());
        }
    }

    std::vector<int> process(std::vector<float> value)
    {
        std::vector<int> result(value.size(), NAN);
        for (size_t ii = 0; ii < value.size(); ++ii)
        {
            methods[ii]->Push(value[ii]);
            result[ii] = methods[ii] -> ReturnVal();
        }
        return result;
    }
};
```

The problem is that how should I properly declare the method vector

```
std::vector<CumSum * if choice == "A" else CumProd *> methods;
```

Thanks a lot!

---

updated the demo code a little bit to make the problem clear.

Comment: There's no such thing, in C++. In C++, the types of all objects must be defined at compile-time. You cannot specify the type of an object at runtime, C++ does not work this way. This is fundamental to C++, there are no exceptions or workarounds. The closest that would come to this would be a `std::variant`-based definition.

Comment: What does the signature for `MethodB` look like? Does it have the same signature as `MethodA`?

Comment: It's has the same structure like MethodA with different computation.@WBuck

Comment: If each class has one function and no state, then they shouldn't be classes at all. Just be honest with yourself and call them what they are: `std::function<void(int&)>`. There's your common type.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo even if they have state, that can still be captured, and the resulting object assigned to a `std::function<void(int&)>`

Answer (score 1):

In this case you could solve this either with polymorphism or with a `std::variant`. This will allow you to store either an instance of `MethodA` or `MethodB` in the `vector`.

### Polymorphism

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

struct Base {
    virtual void push(int& x) const = 0;
    virtual ~Base() = default;
};

struct MethodA : public Base {
    void push(int& x) const override {
        x += 1;
    }
};

struct MethodB : public Base {
    void push(int& x) const override {
        x += 20;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>> methods{};
    methods.push_back(std::make_unique<MethodA>());
    methods.push_back(std::make_unique<MethodB>());

    int initial = 1;
    for (const auto& method : methods) {
        method->push(initial);
        std::cout << initial << '\n';
    }
}
```

### Variant

If you use a [std::variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) take a look at the documentation for it. There are other free functions available for querying what type is currently held and for getting the instance (like `std::get`). Also, the [visitor](https://www.cppstories.com/2018/06/variant/) pattern can be used to clean this up further.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>

struct MethodA {
    void push(int& x) const {
        x += 1;
    }
};

struct MethodB {
    void push(int& x) const {
        x += 20;
    }
};

using MethodTypes = std::variant<MethodA, MethodB>;

int main() {
    std::vector<MethodTypes> methods{};
    methods.push_back(MethodA{});
    methods.push_back(MethodB{});

    int initial = 1;
    for (const auto& method : methods) {
        if (auto* a = std::get_if<MethodA>(&method)) {
            a->push(initial);
            std::cout << initial << '\n';
        }   
        else if (auto* b = std::get_if<MethodB>(&method)) {
            b->push(initial);
            std::cout << initial << '\n';
        }      
    }
}
```

Comment: I think Polymorphism should work. But what if I cannot modify the methods? I updated the problem, does variant still work?

Comment: I'd use `std::visit` and a generic lambda over `get_if`

Comment: @Caleth 100%, so would I. But I didn't want to write the `overload` structure and argument deduction guide (pre C++20) as I figured that would just confuse the OP. I did include a link from Bartek's blog which he shows that pattern.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic issue with C++. As one commenter mentioned, C++ is statically typed so all types of things must be known at compile-time. However, there are two typical ways around that.

## Method 1: Polymorphism

This is a more Java-like solution and will be *every so very slightly* slower at run-time. I am using the smart pointer type `std::unique_ptr` here so there is no manual memory deallocation needed.

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

class MethodBase {
    public:
        virtual void push(int&) = 0;
        virtual ~MethodBase() { }
};

class MethodA :public MethodBase {
    public:
        void push(int& X) override {
            X += 1;
        }
};

// similar for MethodB

void make_vector(std::string choice) {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MethodBase>> methods;
    if (choice == "A") {
        methods.push_back(std::make_unique<MethodA>());
    }
    else { /* ... deal with other method choices ... */ }
    
    // now you can call anything in the MethodBase interface
    int x = 100;
    methods.front()->push(x);
}
```

## Method 2: Templates

C++ templates allow you to easily compile multiple "copies" of any function or class, on-demand as needed. Then you would need some conditional statement elsewhere to decide which "copy" to actually use.

This way will be *ever so slightly faster* than polymorphism at runtime, with no dynamic memory used, but it's also less flexible because you don't really get one variable that can be a vector of either variety.

```
class MethodA {
    public:
        void push(int& X) {
            X += 1;
        }
};

// similar for MethodB

template <typename C>
void make_vector() {
    std::vector<C> methods;
    // populate the vector
    methods.emplace_back(); // constructs a new method object in-place
    // now use it...
    int x = 100;
    methods.front().push(x);
}

int main() {
    std::string choice;
    std::cin >> choice;
    if (choice == "A") {
        make_vector<MethodA>();
    }
    else { /* other cases for MethodB etc */ }
}
```

Comment: Polymorphism should work. Does template still work if I want it inside the class?

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is one member function, you can use `std::function` to do the virtual dispatch for you.

```
std::function<int(int)> methodA()
{
    return [method = MethodA{}](int value) { 
        method.push(value); 
        return method.returnValue(); 
    };
}

std::function<int(int)> methodB()
{
    return [method = MethodB{}](int value) {
        method.push(value); 
        return method.returnValue(); 
    };
}

class Example
{
public:
    const int vector_size = 10;
    std::vector<std::function<int(int)>> methods;

public:
    Example(std::string method)
    {
        for (size_t ii = 0; ii < vector_size; ++ii)
        {
            methods.push_back(choice == "A" ? methodA() : methodB());
        }
    }

    void process(std::vector<float> value)
    {
        for (size_t ii = 0; ii < value.size(); ++ii)
        {
            results[ii] = methods[ii](value[ii]);
        }
    }
};
```

If you are able to modify `MethodA` and `MethodB`, you can simplify that further by renaming `push`:

```
class Sum
{
public:
    int operator()(int X)
    {
        result += x;
        return result;
    }
};

class Product
{
public:
    int operator()(int X)
    {
        result *= x;
        return result;
    }
};

class Example
{
public:
    const int vector_size = 10;
    std::vector<std::function<int(int)>> methods;

public:
    Example(std::string method)
    {
        for (size_t ii = 0; ii < vector_size; ++ii)
        {
            if (choice == "A") {
                methods.push_back(MethodA{});
            } else {
                methods.push_back(MethodB{});
            }
        }
    }

    void process(std::vector<float> value)
    {
        for (size_t ii = 0; ii < value.size(); ++ii)
        {
            results[ii] = methods[ii](value[ii]);
        }
    }
};
```

You could also move the function into a `Cumulative` class.

```
struct CumulativeOp {
    int result;
    std::function<int(int, int)> op;

    void Push(int x)  {
        result = op(result, x);
    }

    int ReturnVal()
    {
        return result;
    }
};

CumulativeOp sum() {
    return { 0, std::plus{} };
}

CumulativeOp prod() {
    return { 1, std::times{} };
}

class Example
{
public:
    const int vector_size = 10;
    std::vector<CumulativeOp> methods;

public:
    Example(std::string method)
      : methods(vector_size, choice == "A" ? sum() : prod())
    {
    }

    void process(std::vector<float> value)
    {
        for (size_t ii = 0; ii < value.size(); ++ii)
        {
            methods[ii].push(value[ii]);
            results[ii] = methods[ii].ReturnVal();
        }
    }
};
```

As an aside, you can't call a function expecting an `int &` by passing a `float &`, which is what `process` is trying to do. You will have to decide you have `int`s or `float`s.

Comment: I got **operand types are incompatible("MethodA" 和 "MethodB") **.

Comment: @Ron oops, see edit

Comment: it only works when methods like a function?

Comment: @Ron Do you need two separate member functions? I'd `return result;` from `push`. This technique only works when you have one function.